# How can I provide a custom gui to code effects?

Tags: codeeffects

New member here. I am using Code Effects with ASP.NET Core. I want to have a custom UI to define rules and actions, using drop downs. How hard would this be?

It's just a matter of generating custom xml and adding it to an xml document for execution @ run time.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as Asnwered if you think it helped with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create such a UI from scratch by yourself. Code Effects' rule editor does not support the alteration of the rule selection flow.